# A way to quick preview .ipynb files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Got a small basic question. I use a Mac, and I used to work in .py files with Sublime 3. One of the things I liked was that when Sublime is closed, for a given file in a folder--if I'm looking for a bit of code--I could hit the spacebar and Macs open a quick preview of the .py document.

Now I'm working in Jupyter Notebook and saving everything as .ipynb files. Now I can't hit the spacebar and glance at files--I launch JN from the command land and it's far slower.

I suspect there are quicker ways to open .ipynb files in browser windows, but what I really want to know is is there a way to quickly preview those file contents from my desktop? Alternatively, is there a way to work in Jupiter Notebook but save the files as .py (and later seamlessly reopen in JN), such that I could still use the great old spacebar trick?

Thanks for you patience with a pretty small question :)

Answer (score 20):

It's been a while since the last answer, but just in case anyone else is looking to use **Mac Quicklook** to preview Jupyter Notebooks .ipynb files, this app does the job:

**Jupyter Notebook Viewer** - https://github.com/tuxu/nbviewer-app

You can either download the app from that page or install using brew cask

```
brew cask install jupyter-notebook-viewer
```

**If the preview is not working you should reload quicklook.**
Just open a terminal windows and run. It worked for me on macOS High Sierra.

```
qlmanage -r
```

Now enjoy quicklook preview for Jupyter Notebook files :)

Comment: With newer brew versions, the command to install it is `brew install --cask jupyter-notebook-viewer`

Comment: nice, although for me, in 12.7, it is just previewing the JSON code... I am upvoting both, but I would go with nbviewere.js, as elsoja mentions on another answer

Answer (score 5):

As an update to the previous answers, I'd like to recommend [nbviewer.js](https://github.com/kokes/nbviewer.js) which is a client-side ipynb renderer. You can use it online at https://kokes.github.io/nbviewer.js/viewer.html

Comment: The online viewer is the easiest solution I found so far. Thank you!

Comment: The nice and easy way, when you have an internet connection and don't want to bother with file conversion.

Comment: You can download the viewer and have it run locally - the conversion doesn't need internet connection itself, it runs everything locally. (I'm the author of nbviewer.js)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same question at the weekend.

I came across two things:

a) this project on Github: https://github.com/jendas1/jupyter-notebook-quick-look

and

b) The Jupyter app which allows you to open Notebooks in Finder on the mac: https://github.com/jendas1/JupyterApp

Caveat - I book marked these, but due to other work I have not had time to download, install or test these.

If you do, please let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to do the same on linux, you can check this out
[nb-viewer](https://github.com/jithu7432/nb-viewer) which lets you preview Jupyter notebooks with a double click!

Answer (score 0):

Update for the most recent version of MacOS (tested on macOS Big Sur v11.6) & newer brew versions:

To install Jupyter Notebook Viewer - https://github.com/tuxu/nbviewer-app follow these steps:

1. `brew install --cask jupyter-notebook-viewer`
2. Manually start `/Applications/Jupyter Notebook Viewer.app` using command + open (to allow a third-party app to be started)
3. `qlmanage -r`