# Is there a way to visualize a Jupyter Notebook without executing it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to view the jupyter notebook in without having to execute, I mean no to open it and iteratively execute commands, just to see it as if it were a pdf or something like that.

I ask this because every time a want to see some code in the notebook I have to go to the specific directory and run the comand `jupyter notebook` and wait until it starts to be able to open the proper file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Macos, give [this](https://github.com/tuxu/nbviewer-app) a shot

Found in this thread:
[A way to quick preview .ipynb files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494230/a-way-to-quick-preview-ipynb-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can view it nicely in PyCharm as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your notebook to html (or other formats) via
`File -> Download as -> html`

Answer (score 0):

You can see them *dropping* the file on **VSCode** too.